# How to Retrieve the Message Body with an Appropriate Encoding in a Custom WCF LOB Adapter?

Tags: biztalk, wcf-lob-adapter

I'm trying to write a basic One-Way custom WCF LOB Adapter for use in BizTalk. However, the target system does not necessarily supports Xml messages. I understand that messages flowing through a custom WCF adapter are *wrapped* in an XML envelope and that the message body can be encoding in one of four ways :

- Xml
- String
- BinHex
- Base64

This settings is governed by the configuration of the `Outbound WCF message body` property, which accepts an property that looks like the following XML fragment :

```
<bts-msg-body xmlns='http://www.microsoft.com/schemas/bts2007' encoding='[xml|base64|hex|string]'/>
```

In the implementation of the `Execute`method in my `CustomAdapterOutboundHandler` class, how is it possible to retrieve which encoding has been specified on the send port configuration ?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the request message on the target system and returns a response message.
    /// If there isn’t a response, this method should return null
    /// </summary>
    public Message Execute(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        // ISSUE: how to retrieve the message body as binary byte[] / stream / whatever ?
        // <bts-msg-body xmlns='http://www.microsoft.com/schemas/bts2007' encoding='[xml|base64|hex|string]'/>

        System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader reader = message.GetReaderAtBodyContents();

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I would take a look here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2010/01/06/manipulate-a-wcf-request-response-using-a-custom-encoder.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found out..

Code like the following will do.

```
object strvalue;
bool result = Message.Properties.TryGetValue("http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2006/01/Adapters/WCF-properties#OutboundXmlTemplate", out strvalue);
if (result)
{
  XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
  xmldoc.LoadXml(strvalue.ToString());
  string btsencoding = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("//*[local-name()='bts-msg-body']").Attributes["encoding"].Value;

// do something useful
}
```